# How to place and merge meshes upon another one (and then delete them)

Tags: mesh

I have copied the 3 meshes on the left (that I created using loopcuts on the "Surface" and placed them onto the right. Now they are lying on the "Surface" at the right end. I would like to simply subtract the 3 copied meshes from the "Surface" they are laying on in order to create 3 holes (doors). How can I do that?
As usual, thanks a lot in advance. You are my saviours.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with some cuttings, duplicate and snaps, but maybe the simplest ways is to use the *Knife Project* tool:

- Separate your 3 faces with <kbd>P</kbd> (*Separate*) > *Selection*. Now your 3 faces are a separate object.
- Select this object, then the main object, and go in *Edit* mode
- Switch to *Ortho Front View*.
- In the *Tools* panel, click on the *Knife Project* button. You've created 3 faces. You can delete the faces in order to create doors.
- You may want to use the knife with <kbd>Z</kbd> (cut through) and <kbd>C</kbd> (cut orthogonally) options activated to create additional edge loops.

[image]